# JSS7 - Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin

Tags: apache, maven

On Ubuntu 16.04 I am installing JSS7 as per https://github.com/RestComm/jss7/wiki/Build-jSS7-from-Source

On Step 7 I get this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) on project scheduler: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] error: Source option 5 is no longer supported. Use 6 or later.
[ERROR] error: Target option 1.5 is no longer supported. Use 1.6 or later.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :scheduler
```

I am new at this any suggestions as to what this means and how to fix it?

Comment: Bumping this thread as I am still stuck